Help with Articles and Linked Cases
I’m trying to identify the Cases/CaseID that are linked to an Knowledge Articles containing a customer field (int type). In other words, I want to fetch the case numbers associated with Articles that have a customer field mentioned in them (not null).
Here’s what I’ve observed so far:
1.Articles contain different versions
2. Cases and Articles are connected through the CaseArticle relationship object.
3. The CaseArticle object provides only the link between Cases and Articles but doesn’t contain customer field information.
I’m looking for a logic or SOQL query that could help fetch the relevant case data as described. If you have any insights or suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it.
